# How to find an element outside its parent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, parent

I have this markup:

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="button"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now i need to find next `panel` just right for `button` element and make some action on it. So i do this but something is not right, can anybody help?

```
var open_bt = $('.button');

open_bt.on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().next().child('.panel').slideDown(100);
});
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$(this).parent().next('.panel').slideDown(100);` should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

You just need to go up one level, and there is no `child` method:

```
open_bt.on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().next('.panel').slideDown(100);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
open_bt.on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').next('.panel').slideDown(100);
});
```